# Install two java versions

Tags: 14.10, java

I have Eclipse installed on my Ubuntu with Java 1.7. I need to compile binary code for Java 1.4.

How to install second Java 1.4 on my Ubuntu since 1.7 I need to run Eclipse.

Comment: You probably do not want to install JDK 1.4 to do this.  The correct approach would be to set the binary level of your project to 1.4 in Eclipse, and continue to use a modern (still supported) JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a second Java version. Open your project settings

- <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on project
- Select <kbd>Properties</kbd>
- In the dialog set the compiler compliance level to <kbd>1.4</kbd>.

[image]